# Do the parenthesis have to be quoted on find command actions?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

The example in the book "Linux Command Line" by William Shotts have the syntax for user-defined actions on find command as:
`-exec command'{}' ';'` to prevent expansion in shell but pretty much everywhere I see the syntax as `-exec command {} \;`. Can anyone explain the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is slightly misleading. check Kamil Maciorowski's comment.

The easiest way to find out will be to use `echo` command. You can check what commands/programs receive after shell expansion.

```sh
$  echo {}
outputs: {}

$  echo '{}'
outputs: {}

$ echo \{\}
outputs  {}
```

so there is no real difference between them. one can use either way.

In fact one can mix and match all of them in a single command. the `find` commands "sees" the same thing.

```sh
-exec echo {} '{}' \{\} \;
```

This isn't true for the `;` though.

```sh
$   echo ;
outputs: # nothing

$   echo ';'
outputs: ;

$   echo \;
outputs: ;
```

Comment: Feedback: The general conclusion is right, but I don't like the means that led you to it. (1) `echo` is not the best tool to check "what commands/programs receive". OK, in this case it prints `{}` as `{}`, but in general [it may interpret the string(s) it gets](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/108618), so you don't really see what it got. (2) `find` is obliged to expand one `{}` per `-exec`; it may or may not expand more (it depends on the implementation). (3) **Advising `find . -exec {} … \;` is irresponsible.** Think what it does and what the consequences may be. You set a trap.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski you are right on every point, do I delete my post?

Comment: I wouldn't delete. The answer answers the question somehow. I wouldn't call it *highly* inaccurate. In this particular case `echo` and (some implmentations of) `find` bring useful conclusions. After you fixed (3), the answer is no longer a trap. The trap was my main objection.

Comment: Thanks @KamilMaciorowski I would +1 if I could